# Binding Treeview control with XML Datasource with incorrect node title

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to bind the Treeview control to XML datasource which is binded properly, the only problem I am having is the text displayed for the tree nodes is incorrect. Please refer to the code below.

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" ShowCheckBoxes="All" >
 <DataBindings>                                                        ``
   <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="menuItem" TextField="text" NavigateUrlField="url" Text="Permissions" Depth="2" SelectAction="None"/>                                          
  </DataBindings>
```

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<menu>
  <menuItem text="Home" url="~/Default.aspx?id=e058511b-b7d9-4d39-b194-cf803014777" mid="08f360dc-   a9cf-4724-a595-66f7ca01c04e" predeficon="homeico" />
  <menuItem text="Bio" url="~/Default.aspx"  icon="~/common/theme/smoothadmin/img/cog.png">
    <subMenu>
      <menuItem text="Reg" url="~\Modules\Bio\Reg.aspx"/>
      <menuItem text="Mem" url="~\Modules\Bio\Mem.aspx"/>      
    </subMenu>
  </menuItem>    
  <menuItem text="Por" url="~/Default.aspx?"  icon="~/common/theme/smoothadmin/img/cog.png">
    <subMenu>
      <menuItem text="General">
        <subMenu>
          <menuItem text="Make Appointment" url="~\Modules\Portals\Gen.aspx"/>          
        </subMenu>
      </menuItem>
    </subMenu>
  </menuItem>
</menu>
```

The tree view loads fine, but the text for treeNodes are displyed, where as the text for menu such as (Home, Bio,Reg, Mem etc) is not displyed.

- menu

  - menuItem
  - menuItem

    - subMenu
    - menuItem
    - menuItem
    - menuItem
    - subMenu

      - menuItem
      - subMenu

        - menuItem

Comment: why you have `Text="Permissions"`? try by removing that

Comment: @Damith I have removed the Text="Permissions" property but still the treeview is loaded with nodes text instead of the actual text.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
 <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1">
    <DataBindings>
        <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="menuItem" TextField="text" NavigateUrlField="url"  />
    </DataBindings>
</asp:TreeView>
```

It didn't work initially because one of the menuitems in the xml was missing a url value.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue. As this question is the first link in google - adding answer.
As long as all the "text" properties in XML were set - my solution was to write like that:

```
<asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="" TextField="text" NavigateUrlField="url"  />
```